# Why does increasing number of processes when multi-threading with PySpark mess up how the actual code works?

Tags: python, apache-spark, multiprocessing, pyspark, threadpool

I have separate avro part files (with different schema types) which I have to loop through, read and store, so that I can perform other operations and ultimately merge them.

I am using the Python multiprocessing package to call ThreadPool and apply my custom function on an iterable of filepaths. With a small number of threads, the code works fine. But as I keep on increasing the number of worker processes, though the code runs faster, the output values are inaccurate and all messed up.

This is my scenario in brief:

File A: count of rows - 119158
File B: count of rows - 247487

Sample code:

```
#filepath_list = list of the two filepaths

def my_custom_function(k):
    quotes_df = sqlc.read.format("com.databricks.spark.avro").load(k)
    quotes_df.registerTempTable("quotes_df")
    quotes_each = sqlc.sql("Select column_1, column_2 from quotes_df")
    return quotes_each.count()

tpool = ThreadPool(np)
results = tpool.map(my_custom_function, filepath_list)
tpool.close()
tpool.join()
```

When np = 1, print(results) yields (119158, 247487).
But with np > 1, print(results) yields either (119158, 119158) or (247487, 247487) randomly.

Note: As the list of filepaths keep growing, the 'error threshold' of np grows as well. E.g. with 50 filepaths, the code runs fine for np = 4 but starts getting messed up for np > 4.

Does any one have any thoughts about why this should be happening and what could be some potential solutions?

Thanks.

Comment: It happens because your code is not threadsafe. You could start with not depending on metastore name but there can be other issues here.

Comment: Hi @LostInOverflow, thanks for your thoughts. I implemented a global lock to pass to my processes and that did the trick! Much appreciated.